# Html image doesn't change

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, image, amazon-s3

I'm using aws s3, where 3 images are stored. I replaced 2 images because the previous had poor quality. I reference their Object URL in HTML. The problem is that when I send e-mail with this html, the old images are used. I tried using online html viewer with the same html and it worked properly, the old images were replaced. The question is why does e-mail's html not working properly. I'm using aws ses to send e-mails. When you use object url, it redirects you on the correct images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing image name, its still using cached images atmost

Comment: It actually worked, thank you!